# QFileDialog::getSaveFileName does not show extension in filter

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

Qt 6.6.0 in Ubuntu 23.10.
Here my short code:

```
QSettings settings;
QDir defaultDir(settings.value("Default path", QDir::home().absolutePath()).toString());
QString filter = "SQL Database (*.sql)";
QString file = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("New file"), defaultDir.path(), filter, &filter);
```

It actually works, but the filter in the file dialog does not show the extension:

[image]

I would like to show also `(*.sql)`.
I tried some hacks, like:

```
QString filter = "SQL Database (*.sql) (*.sql)";
```

or

```
QString filter = "SQL Database \(*.sql\) (*.sql)";
```

but none works.
What is the right syntax in order to show the extension in the file dialog?

Comment: That is the system file dialog. If you don't want it and want to customize it, use the `DontUseNativeDialog` option.